# why the char buffer content size is 4 bytes?

Tags: c, buffer

I call the  recv()  that receive data from socket and print the end of buffer content by hex

```
char nbuff[BUFSZ];
while ((r_n=recv(sfd,rbuff,B_BUF,MSG_EOF))>-1)
{
    printf("r_n:%d eob_p:%x\n",r_n,rbuff[r_n-1]);
    if (r_n==0)
    {
        break;
    }
    memset(rbuff,0,B_BUF);
}
```

the result is

```
r_n:1674 eob_p:3c
r_n:1228 eob_p:76
r_n:2456 eob_p:ffffff81
r_n:1228 eob_p:4b
r_n:1228 eob_p:49
r_n:2456 eob_p:57
r_n:1417 eob_p:ffffff82
```

I am confused about why the result is 4 bytes.
I create another code to print the file that saved from buff

```
int main ()
{
    char buff[11686];
    memset(buff,0,11686);
    FILE *in =fopen("web/www.sse.com.cn.html","r");
    fread(buff,11686,1,in);
    for (int i = 0; i <  11686 ; i++)
    {
        printf("%x\n",buff[i]);
    }
}
```

the result is

```
....
buff[11684]:60
buff[11685]:ffffff82
```

why the char buff 's contents size is 4 bytes **buff[11685]:ffffff82**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages.  What is `BBB`?  A macro?  A function?    Which result is 4 bytes?  The negative values stored in `rbuff`?  What is the type of `nbuff`? That's not a complete variable definition.  It is also immaterial; the variable used in the code is `rbuff`.  How are the other variables defined?  I expect `rbuff` is a `char` buffer and `char` is a signed type on your machine, and you're storing values which are negative in `rbuff`, so when they're converted to `int` in the call to `printf()`, they are negative integers, printed in hex.

Comment: To always print 2-digit hex for the characters, use `%.2X` (or `%.2x` if you prefer) and pass either `(unsigned char)rbuff[r_n-1]` or `rbuff[r_n-1] & 0xFF` as the argument.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I  sorry about i ask a unclear question. My question is why i print the char buff's content that come from the file  is not equal to  1 bytes .

Comment: As I explained in my previous "thicker" comment, the call to `printf()` promotes the character value from `char` to `int` (because of the rules for calling 'variadic' functions like `printf()` which have an ellipsis at the end of their declaration — `int printf(const char * restrict format, ...);`).  And when a (signed) `char` containing a negative value (between 0x80 and 0xFF when looked at as an unsigned char value) is converted to `int`, it is sign-extended, so the 1-byte negative number becomes a 4-byte integer with the three most significant bytes all 0xFF (assuming two's complement).

Comment: The fix is as diagnosed in my previous "thinner" comment — coerce the value to be an `unsigned char` or mask it with 0xFF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Diagnosis

In the second example, `buff` is a `char` buffer and plain `char` is a signed type on your machine, and you're storing values which are negative in `buff`, so when they're converted to `int` in the call to `printf()`, they are negative integers (of small magnitude), printed in hex.

#### ISO/IEC 9899:2018

Actually, the links are to an online draft of C11, not C18, in HTML which allows links to the relevant paragraphs in the standard.  AFAIK, these details have not changed between C90, C99, C11 and C18 anyway.

The standard says that the plain `char` type is equivalent to either `signed char` or `unsigned char`.

[§6.2.5 Types ¶15](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p15):

> The three types `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are collectively called the character types. The implementation shall define `char` to have the same range, representation, and behavior as either `signed char` or `unsigned char`.<sup>45)</sup>
>
> <sup>45)</sup> `CHAR_MIN`, defined in `<limits.h>`, will have one of the values 0 or `SCHAR_MIN`, and this can be used to distinguish the two options. Irrespective of the choice made, `char` is a separate type from the other two and is not compatible with either.

[§6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters and integers ¶2,3](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1p2):

> 2 The following may be used in an expression wherever an int or unsigned int may be used:
>
> - An object or expression with an integer type (other than `int` or `unsigned int`) whose integer conversion rank is less than or equal to the rank of `int` and `unsigned int`.
> - A bit-field of type `_Bool`, `int`, `signed int`, or `unsigned int`.
>
> If an `int` can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`. These are called the *integer promotions*.<sup>58)</sup> All other types are unchanged by the integer promotions.
>
> 3 The integer promotions preserve value including sign. As discussed earlier, whether a "plain" `char` is treated as signed is implementation-defined.
>
> <sup>58)</sup> The integer promotions are applied only: as part of the usual arithmetic conversions, to certain argument expressions, to the operands of the unary `+`, `-`, and `~` operators, and to both operands of the shift operators, as specified by their respective subclasses.

[§6.5.2.6 Function calls ¶6,7](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p6):

> 6 If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a prototype, the integer promotions are performed on each argument, and arguments that have type `float` are promoted to `double`. These are called the *default argument promotions*. If the number of arguments does not equal the number of parameters, the behavior is undefined. If the function is defined with a type that includes a prototype, and either the prototype ends with an ellipsis (`, ...`) or the types of the arguments after promotion are not compatible with the types of the parameters, the behavior is undefined. If the function is defined with a type that does not include a prototype, and the types of the arguments after promotion are not compatible with those of the parameters after promotion, the behavior is undefined, except for the following cases:
>
> - one promoted type is a signed integer type, the other promoted type is the corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value is representable in both types;
> - both types are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of a character type or void.
>
> 7 If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does include a prototype, the arguments are implicitly converted, as if by assignment, to the types of the corresponding parameters, taking the type of each parameter to be the unqualified version of its declared type. The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter. The default argument promotions are performed on trailing arguments.

#### Exegesis

Note the last two sentences of §6.5.2.6 ¶7 — when the `char` values are promoted by the 'integer promotions', they are promoted to a (signed) `int`, and the negative values remain negative.  Since an `int` has 4 bytes, and all the machines you're likely to have available use two's-complement arithmetic, the most significant 3 bytes of the value will be 0xFF each.

#### Prescription

To always print 2-digit hex for the characters, use `%.2X` (or `%.2x` if you prefer; you can also use either `%02X` or `%02x`) and pass either `(unsigned char)rbuff[r_n-1]` or `rbuff[r_n-1] & 0xFF` as the argument (using the variables from the first example).  Or, using the variables from the second example:

```
printf("%.2X\n", (unsigned char)buff[i]);
printf("%.2X\n", buff[i] & 0xFF);
```